# Eclipse code formatter/interpreter 5.4.3

Tags: php, eclipse

Since the new PHP 5.4(.3) release my eclipse is confused by the new things I do like:

```
$array =  [];
```

I changed the formatter/interpreter earlier in eclipse because he couldn't handle functions in functions but my question now is where do I get the new formatter/interpreter?

Comment: @hakre why that tag change?

Comment: I just removed the PHP-5.4 tag. I do not think it is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already added to the new Eclipse Zend PDT so its fixed